# Curve in Geometry node: how to add a control point to the spline

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

I guess this is yet a simple question.

I am trying to increase the control point on a curve using Geometry node.

Please note that the curve is created outside the geometry node using Add menu option. For illustration purpose, i am using a curve circle.

I have attached the screenshots of what i had attempted.

Without modification of control point
[image]

With addition of a control point
[image]

But when i increase the control point, the resolution seems to be reset.

Thanks in advance.

Added Blend file

[image]

Comment: can u pls provide a blend file to just support lazy people like me which are than attracted much more to help you than just having to rebuild everything...?

Comment: Please don't take offense, but please, please change the theme (at least for the screenshots). ...please ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately it is not clear to me what exactly you mean, but please have a look at the nodes `Set Spline Resolution` and `Resample Curve`. ...Maybe this will help you.

Comment: @Chris, good point. I have uploaded the blend file. Hope i have done it right.

Comment: @quellenform, I understand. Will try and change theme.

Comment: i think the problem is with my understanding of how the bezier works when there are 5 control points. I was trying to retain the shape (in this case, circle) even when the control point is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To be honest, I'm not quite clear what exactly your goal is, but here's a short explanation of what exactly happens here:

If you have a circle as starting point (*Bezier circle*), and apply the node `Resample Curve` to it, the type of the curve will be changed from *Bezier* to *Poly*.

Thereby the typical properties of the *Bezier curve* are discarded, and with it also the *Curve Handles*, which were available for the control of the curve before.

[image]

[image]

This can be seen in the *Spreadsheet* in the column *curve_type*.

One possibility to get a *Bezier curve* in the end and to increase the spline points would be to change the type of the curve with `Set Spline Type` and to smooth the curve handles with `Set Handle Type`.

However, with a small number of points this unfortunately does not lead to an exact circle:

[image]

But I guess that you are not really interested in the number of control points, but in the resolution of the curve.

You can change this directly in the *Object Data Properties* with the field *Resolution Preview U*, or in *Geometry Nodes* with the node `Set Spline Resolution`:

[image]

<sub>*PS: If this answer does not help you, please be so kind and explain us more exactly what your goal is.*</sub>

Comment: that was helpful. "the typical properties of the Bezier curve are discarded" was exactly what happened when i was adding another control point to the existing curve.